# Server info embeds doesn't show on discord server, only says interaction failed and no error in terminal, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, embed

I was trying to make an embed info command with "info user" and "info server" subcommand. When I try to show the owner's user tag in the embeds it shows undefined so I was told to change `get(ownerId)` to `fetch`, but was then told to resolve the promise. Same goes with the member, where I was trying to see how many bots there are in the server, it always show 1 whereas there were 5. Now the terminal doesn't show error when I do the info server command, but in the discord channel it shows interaction failed. The info user command works perfectly. How should I fix this?

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('info')
        .setDescription('returns info based on input')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("user")
                .setDescription("get the information of a member mentioned")
                .addUserOption(option => option.setName("member").setDescription("Tag a member")))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("server")
                .setDescription("info about this server")),
    async execute(interaction, client, user, members) {
        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "user") {
            const user = interaction.options.getUser("member");
            if (user) {
                const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
                const userEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`${user.username}'s Information:`)
                    .setDescription(`This is a member in ${interaction.guild.name} :raised_hands:`)
                    .setAuthor(user.username, user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .addFields(
                        { name: `Username`, value: `This member's username is ${user.username}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Tag`, value: `This member's tag is #${user.discriminator}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Joined Discord`, value: new Date(user.createdTimestamp).toDateString(), inline: true },

                        { name: `Joined server`, value: new Date(member.joinedTimestamp).toDateString(), inline: true },

                        { name: `Is this member a bot?`, value: `${user.bot}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Nickname`, value: member.nickname || "None", inline: true },

                        { name: `Role count`, value: `${member.roles.cache.size - 1}`, inline: true },

                    )
                    .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setColor("#F2A4D3")
                    .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

                if (interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.cache.has("869759848747786262")) {
                    userEmbed.addFields({ name: `Boost status`, value: `This member has been boosting our server since ${new Date(member.premiumSinceTimestamp).toDateString()} :grin:`, inline: true }, { name: `\u200B`, value: `\u200B`, inline: true })
                } else {
                    userEmbed.addFields({ name: `Boost status`, value: `This noob isn't boosting our server :neutral_face:`, inline: true }, { name: `\u200B`, value: `\u200B`, inline: true })
                }
                await interaction.reply({ embeds: [userEmbed] });
            } else {
                const user = interaction.user
                const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
                const selfEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`Your User Information (narcissistic much??):`)
                    .setDescription(`You're in ${interaction.guild.name} :raised_hands:`)
                    .setAuthor(user.username, user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .addFields(
                        { name: `Username`, value: `Your username is ${user.username}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Tag`, value: `Your tag is #${user.discriminator}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Joined Discord`, value: `You joined discord on ${new Date(user.createdTimestamp).toDateString()}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Joined server`, value: `You joined this server on ${new Date(member.joinedTimestamp).toDateString()}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Are you a bot?`, value: `${user.bot}`, inline: true },

                        { name: `Nickname`, value: member.nickname || "None", inline: true },

                        { name: `Role count`, value: `${member.roles.cache.size - 1}`, inline: true },

                    )
                    .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setColor("#F2A4D3")
                    .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

                if (interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.cache.has("869759848747786262")) {
                    selfEmbed.addFields({ name: `Boost status`, value: `OOO you've been boosting our server since ${new Date(member.premiumSinceTimestamp).toDateString()}, so swag :grin:`, inline: true }, { name: `\u200B`, value: `\u200B`, inline: true })
                } else {
                    selfEmbed.addFields({ name: `Boost status`, value: `You're not boosting our server, get nitro and boost it right now you idiot :neutral_face:`, inline: true }, { name: `\u200B`, value: `\u200B`, inline: true })
                }
                await interaction.reply({ embeds: [selfEmbed] });
                //await interaction.reply(`Username: ${user.username}\nYour ID: ${user.id}`);
            }
        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "server") {
            const server = interaction.guild;
            const user = await client.users.fetch(interaction.guild.ownerId);
            const members = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
            const channels = interaction.guild.channels.cache;
            const emojis = interaction.guild.emojis.cache;
            const date = new Date(interaction.guild.createdTimestamp).toDateString();

            const serverEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${server.name}'s Information`)
                .setAuthor(server.name, server.iconURL())
                .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .addFields(
                    { name: `Owner`, value: `<@${interaction.guild.ownerId}>, ${user.tag}` },
                    { name: `Server ID`, value: `${server.id}`, inline: true },
                    { name: `Total Members`, value: `${server.memberCount}`, inline: true },
                    //{ name: `Online`, value: `${server.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.presence.status = "online").size}`, inline: true},
                    { name: `Time created`, value: `${moment(interaction.guild.createdTimestamp).format("LT")}, ${moment(interaction.guild.createdTimestamp).format("LL")}, ${moment(interaction.guild.createdTimestamp).fromNow()}`},
                    //{ name: `Time created`, value: `${moment(interaction.guild.createdTimestamp.toLocale()).format("LT)")}, ${moment(date).format("LL")}`},
                    { name: `Emojis`, value: `${emojis.size}`},
                    {name: `Regular emojis`, value: `${emojis.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}`},
                    {name: `Animated emojis`, value: `${emojis.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}`},
                    {name: `Human`, value: `${members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`},
                    {name: `Bots`, value: `${members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}`},
                    {name: `Text channels`, value: `${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === "text").size}`},
                    {name: `Voice channels`, value: `${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === "voice").size}`},
                    {name: `Boost`, value: `${interaction.guild.premiumSubscriptionCount || "0"}`},
                    {name: `Online`, value: `${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === "online")}`},
                )
                .setImage(server.iconURL())
                .setTimestamp()
                .setColor("#F2A4D3")
                .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [serverEmbed] });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply("No sub command was used.");
        }
    },
};
```